# Setting selected value in SelectList isn't working using DropDownListFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a SelectList for a drop down

```
public class EditDeviceViewModel
{
   public SelectList DeviceTypeList { get; set; }
   public int SelectedDeviceType { get; set; }

   public EditDeviceViewModel(Device device, IEnumerable<DeviceType> DeviceTypes)
   {
      ...
      DeviceTypeList = new SelectList(DeviceTypes.OrderBy(t => t.Type), 
                                      "ID", 
                                      "Type", 
                                      device.DeviceType.ID);
      SelectedDeviceType = device.DeviceType.ID;
   }
}
```

Then in my view I am creating a drop down using the Html helper

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDeviceType, 
                      Model.DeviceTypeList, 
                      new { id = "devicetypelist" })
```

When the view is rendered, the value I selected when initialising the `SelectList` isn't selected.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you passing the model to the view?  Are you sure that device.DeviceType.ID has a valid value in the DeviceTypes list?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Even if I replace device.DeviceType.ID with a number that I know to be in the list it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DropDown list will use the value of `SelectedDeviceType` property as the selected value. What you can do is set the property value when you construct the model

```
public class EditDeviceViewModel
{
   public SelectList DeviceTypeList { get; set; }
   public int SelectedDeviceType { get; set; }

   public EditDeviceViewModel(Device device, IEnumerable<DeviceType> DeviceTypes)
   {
      ...
      DeviceTypeList = new SelectList(DeviceTypes.OrderBy(t => t.Type), 
                                      "ID", 
                                      "Type");

      SelectedDeviceType = device.DeviceType.ID;
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep was already doing that, sorry should have included that in the question. Edited it now.

Comment: @link664 check the value of `SelectedDeviceType` when you pass the model from the controller.

Comment: just realised that you had given me the correct answer, I just hadn't realised you had removed the selectedValue parameter from your SelectList constructor.

Comment: yes, this is a tricky one, not sure if this is a bug, but it has bitten me a couple times

Answer (score 1):

THe first argument to DropDownListFor must be the variable that holds your selected value.  Are you setting SelectedDeviceType anywhere?

Comment: Yep was already doing that, sorry should have included that in the question. Edited it now.

Comment: Try removing the last parameter in the SelectList